# Getting error while trying to start http services

Tags: php, linux, apache, http, amazon-ec2

In My AWS ec-2 instance,
I am getting an error:

```
 Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/7.0/modules/php_openssl.dll'
```

Whenever I am running command:

```
sudo systemctl start httpd
```

My server is not responding to http requestes.

Answer (score 1):

does the library exist in your system? what is the output of

```
ls -l /usr/lib64/php/7.0/modules/php_openssl.dll
```

This file should be bundled with php. Try uninstalling and reinstalling php again.

Comment: Well I have commented that line in file which adds this library for now and get rid of this issue temporary.